# Unattended RPA with Power Automate Premium and Hosted RPA Add-On: Compatibility with Own VPS (EC2)

Tags: power-automate, rpa, power-automate-desktop

We are in the process of implementing an unattended RPA solution and are considering the usage of Power Automate Premium, which is priced at $15 per month, in conjunction with the hosted RPA add-on priced at $250.

Our main concern is whether this combination will enable us to develop automation using our own Virtual Private Server (VPS), specifically an EC2 instance. We have a client with a requirement for an RPA service, and ensuring compatibility with our infrastructure is crucial.

Any insights, particularly from those with experience in Microsoft's customer service, would be highly appreciated. Thank you for your assistance in this matter.

I've tried looking for documentation on Microsoft Power Automate and watched YouTube tutorials, but couldn't find what I need. If there are any experts in Power Automate (Hosted RPA) who could offer guidance or recommend resources, I would be grateful for your help. Thanks!